# Error throwing while running reduce function in erlang for pagiantion

Tags: python, erlang, riak, erlang-shell, erlang-ports

I have written my reduce phase like for pagination form the HTML side where backend gets requests of from 0 to count 10 so that i have to display return those values in the reduce phase:

```
reduce_paginate1(L,Arg) ->
  [lists:sublist(lists:sort(L),Arg)].


reduce_paginate2(L,[Frm,Cnt]) ->
  case Frm > length(L) of
    true -> [];
    false -> [lists:sublist(L,Frm,Cnt)]
  end.
```

I am calling this from python-riak client in my application as:

```
query.map(['conditions', 'mapfields_check'],
          {
            'arg': [['user_email', 'eq', 'xxxxxxx@gmail.com'],
                    ['template_name', 'assigned_camps']]
          });

query.reduce(['pagiante', 'reduce_paginate1'],
             {'arg':frm + count});

query.reduce(['pagiante', 'reduce_paginate2'],
             {'arg' : [frm + 1,count],"reduce_phase_only1" : True});
```

It is throwing error as:

```
 Error running MapReduce operation. 
 Headers:
     {
        'date': 'Tue, 24 Jun 2014 07:56:38 GMT', 
        'content-length': '1388', 
        'content-type': 'text/html', 
        'http_code': 500, 
        'server': 'MochiWeb/1.1 WebMachine/1.10.0 (never breaks eye contact)'
     }
 Body: 
     '<html>
        <head><title>500 Internal Server Error</title></head>
        <body>
        <h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
        The server encountered an error while processing this request:<br>
        <pre>
          {error,
           {
            exit,
            {json_encode, {bad_term,{reduce,1}}},\n
            [{
              mochijson2,json_encode,2,\n
              [{file,"src/mochijson2.erl"},{line,149}]
             },\n
             {
              mochijson2,\'-json_encode_proplist/2-fun-0-\',3,\n
              [{file,"src/mochijson2.erl"},{line,167}]
             },\n
             {
              lists,foldl,3,[{file,"lists.erl"},{line,1197}]
             },\n
             {
              mochijson2,json_encode_proplist,2,\n
              [{file,"src/mochijson2.erl"},{line,170}]
             },\n
             {
              riak_kv_wm_mapred,send_error,2,\n
              [
               {file,"src/riak_kv_wm_mapred.erl"},\n
               {line,70}
              ]
             },\n
             {
              riak_kv_wm_mapred,pipe_mapred,2,\n
              [
               {file,"src/riak_kv_wm_mapred.erl"},\n
               {line,173}
              ]
             },\n
             {
              webmachine_resource,resource_call,3,\n
              [
               {file,"src/webmachine_resource.erl"},\n
               {line,186}
              ]
             },\n
             {
              webmachine_resource,do,3,\n
              [
               {file,"src/webmachine_resource.erl"},\n
               {line,142}
              ]
             }
            ]
           }
          }
        </pre>
        <P><HR><ADDRESS>mochiweb+webmachine web server</ADDRESS>
        </body>
      </html>'
```

Please, suggest me how to overcome this issue.

Comment: If you run the query without the reduce phases, what does the data look like?

Comment: The error you're receiving actually seems to be suggesting that you have malformed data in your database, and it's failing when trying to encode the data to JSON. Specifically, it seems to be encountering the tuple `{reduce, 1}` outside of the context of a struct.